# Get String after String.indexof in c#

Tags: c#, string, substring

I am currently developing an application in C# where I need to get the substring after a certain character within the string.

```
else if (txtPriceLimit.Text.Contains('.') && char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar))
{
    int index = txtPriceLimit.Text.IndexOf('.');
    string pennies = txtPriceLimit.Text.Substring(index, txtPriceLimit.Text.Length);
    Console.WriteLine("Pennies: " + pennies);
}
```

For some reason it keeps on coming up with an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. How can I get the contents of the string from the index to the end?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

**EDIT:**
Just found that the various things I have tried that have been suggested do seem to work except its not getting the value from the last button pressed into the text field. 
I am using the KeyPress Event in order to do this.

For example if I enter .123 it will only print 12. Then if I add 4 on the end it will print 123

Comment: To add to Donut's answer.  The reason your `Substring()` call is failing is because you're asking for `txtPriceLimit.Text.Length` characters starting from `index`.  Meaning the entire length of your string would have to be `index + txtPriceLimit.Text.Length`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The [overload of `String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) that you're using takes a start index and a specified length. As the start index, you're using the location of "`.`", but as the length, you're using the length of the entire string. If `index` is **greater than 0**, this will cause an exception (as you've seen).

Instead, just use this:

```
string pennies = txtPriceLimit.Text.Substring(index + 1);
```

This will get all of the characters within `txtPriceLimit.Text` **after** the location of "`.`". Note that we need to add 1 to the index; otherwise "`.`" will be included in the resulting substring.

Comment: Thanks, I did try this but it is only getting the values before the indexof

Comment: @Boardy Not quite sure what you mean here, could you please clarify? Does `txtPriceLimit.Text` contain more than one period?

Comment: @Donut No only contains 1 one period. Sorry I misread the output it is getting the numbers after the point except for the last character. For example if I type 100.501 instead of it printing 501 it will print 50

Comment: @Boardy: It looks like you're doing this in a keydown handler or some such. Have you checked to see that `txtPriceLimit.Text` has been updated to include the number that the user just entered?

Comment: @Donut I'm using a KeyPress. Surely calling txtPriceLimit.Text should get the last entered character when the method was called but it doesn't seem to be doing it

Comment: @Boardy: Surely, the control should *not* get the key that was pressed. The `KeyPress` event allows you to set the `Handled` property of the `KeypressEventArgs` to `true` if you want to prevent the control from processing the character.  See the Remarks section of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.aspx.

Comment: Just an example : txtPriceLimit.Text.Substring(txtPriceLimit.Text.LastIndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1)

Answer (score 4):

Just try doing this instead

```
string pennies = txtPriceLimit.Text.Split('.')(1);
```

This assumes that there is only 1 `.` in the string, and that there will be 1 in the string.

Comment: Assumes there's only two string parts.

Comment: `string pennies = txtPriceLimit.Text.Split('.').LastOrDefault()`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a lot of people are finding this useful, so I wanted to contribute some code I created to the community.

This is an extension method I wrote that will return the text in **this string txt** following the parameter **string value**:

### Listing 1:

```
public static string TextFollowing(this string txt, string value) {
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) {
    int index = txt.IndexOf(value);
    if (-1 < index) {
      int start = index + value.Length;
      if (start <= txt.Length) {
        return txt.Substring(start);
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

### Example 1:

```
string exampleText = "My cat is bad.";
string afterCat = exampleText.TextFollowing("cat");
// afterCat = " is bad.";
```

For people who have not come over to Extension Methods, you can get the same results out of a tool similarly defined like this:

### Listing 2:

```
public static string TextFollowing(string searchTxt, string value) {
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTxt) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) {
    int index = searchTxt.IndexOf(value);
    if (-1 < index) {
      int start = index + value.Length;
      if (start <= searchTxt.Length) {
        return searchTxt.Substring(start);
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

### Example 2:

```
string exampleText = "My cat is bad.";
string afterCat = TextFollowing(exampleText, "cat");
// afterCat = " is bad.";
```

In each of the examples above, if `exampleText` had been an Empty String, the search value had been `null` or Empty String, or if the search value is not found, the resulting string would be `null`.

I have this code in my list of tools where it is used in countless places in numerous projects, and it always works great.

Answer (score 2):

Use this , this will definitely work :-

```
else if (txtPriceLimit.Text.Contains('.') && char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar))
{
    int index = txtPriceLimit.Text.IndexOf('.');
    string pennies = txtPriceLimit.Text.Substring(index+1, txtPriceLimit.Text.Length-(index+1));
    pennies=pennies+e.KeyChar.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("Pennies: " + pennies);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Donut's answer is the right one.

Because the second parameter of Substring is **length** not 'end index', his answer is the much cleaner equivalent of:

```
string pennies = txtPriceLimit.Text.Substring(index, index-txtPriceLimit.Text.Length);
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this but it is still coming up with an indexoutofrange exception

Comment: KeyPress event is to let you accept or deny - the text has NOT been updated yet - and the pending character is in e.KeyChar.  If you are not rejecting input - change to using txtPriceLimit.TextChanged event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

### VisualBasic version

Code to find sub-string, if found, return the trailing part - the remainder of the string immediately behind (trailing the end) of the found sub-string.

**jp2code**'s answer fitted my purpose in an elegant fashion. In addition to examples, the author also indicated the code has been well tried and tested over time. **VisualBasic** equivalent of his/her code:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module StringExtensions
    <Extension()>
    Public Function TextFollowing(txt As String, value As String) As String
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt) AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) Then
            Dim index As Integer = txt.IndexOf(value)
            If -1 < index Then
                Dim start As Integer = index + value.Length
                If start <= txt.Length Then
                    Return txt.Substring(start)
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Module
```

The code has been tested using **VS Community 2017**.

### Usage example

```
Dim exampleText As String = "C-sharp to VisualBasic"
Dim afterCSharp = exampleText.TextFollowing("to")
'afterCSharp = " VisualBasic"
```

The extension method `TextFollowing()` is now avaliable to `String` objects.

1. Line 1: `exampleText` is `String` and therefore our extension method is available
2. Line 2: `exampleText.TextFollowing()` uses the extension method

### Complementary method

It may be useful to have the complementary method - obtain the preceding portion of the string. The complementary extension methods are written and placed together in one combined code module:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module StringExtensions
    <Extension()>
    Public Function TextFollowing(txt As String, value As String) As String
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt) AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) Then
            Dim index As Integer = txt.IndexOf(value)
            If -1 < index Then
                Dim start As Integer = index + value.Length
                If start <= txt.Length Then
                    Return txt.Substring(start)
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Return Nothing
    End Function
    <Extension()>
    Public Function TextPreceding(txt As String, value As String) As String
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt) AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) Then
            Dim index As Integer = txt.IndexOf(value)
            If -1 < index Then
                Return txt.Substring(0, index)
            End If
        End If
        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Module
```

### Usage example

```
Dim exampleText As String = "C-sharp to VisualBasic"
Dim beforeVisualBasic = exampleText.TextPreceding("to")
'beforeVisualBasic = "C-sharp "
```

In my use case, it is necessary to check if `LargeString.Contains(SmallString)` prior to using these extension methods. For faster code execution this could have been combined with the extension methods presented above which I did not. This is because no slow-ness is experienced therefore the preference is on code reusability.